# How can I create a changing number of buttons based off a dynamic list?

Tags: c#, android

To clarify, I have a list that changes based on how many jobs are being performed by employees. I want to make a page in an android app that has a button for each job in the list, and the list will grow and shrink in number of jobs. I would like to do it in a way that allows me to change the button color and margin, but I have not found a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume since you have labeled this as C# and Android, that you are working with Xamarin.  I believe the best way to accomplish your goal, is to create the buttons dynamically.

Starting from a blank android solution, I made the following changes:

### Main.axml

Added id "contentLayout" to the main layout view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/contentLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

### MainActivity

Created a basic Job class, and set background color by "Priority" as an example of how the process might work.

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Views;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Android.Content;

namespace App1
{
    [Activity(Label = "App1", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        private LinearLayout _contentLayout;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            _contentLayout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.contentLayout);

            List<MyJob> jobs = GetJobs();
            _contentLayout.AddView(GetButtons(this, jobs));
        }

        private List<MyJob> GetJobs()
        {
            return new List<MyJob>()
                   {
                       new MyJob() { Text = "First Job", Priority = MyJob.PriorityEnum.Low },
                       new MyJob() { Text = "Second Job", Priority = MyJob.PriorityEnum.Medium },
                       new MyJob() { Text = "Third Job", Priority = MyJob.PriorityEnum.High },
                       new MyJob() { Text = "Fourth Job", Priority = MyJob.PriorityEnum.Low },
                   };
        }

        private ViewGroup GetButtons(Context context, List<MyJob> jobs)
        {
            if (jobs == null || jobs.Count == 0)
            {
                return null;
            }

            LinearLayout buttonLayout = new LinearLayout(context)
                                        {
                                            Orientation = Orientation.Vertical,
                                            LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent)
                                        };

            foreach (MyJob job in jobs)
            {
                Button button = new Button(context)
                                {
                                    LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent),
                                    Text = job.Text,
                                };

                button.SetBackgroundColor(GetButtonColor(job.Priority));

                buttonLayout.AddView(button);
            }

            return buttonLayout;
        }

        private Android.Graphics.Color GetButtonColor(MyJob.PriorityEnum priority)
        {
            switch (priority)
            {
                case MyJob.PriorityEnum.High:
                    return new Android.Graphics.Color(255, 0, 0);
                case MyJob.PriorityEnum.Medium:
                    return new Android.Graphics.Color(255, 255, 0);
                case MyJob.PriorityEnum.Low:
                default:
                    return new Android.Graphics.Color(0, 255, 0);
            }
        }
    }

    internal class MyJob
    {
        public enum PriorityEnum { Low, Medium, High }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public PriorityEnum Priority { get; set; }
    }
}
```

### Output

[Screen grab of final output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmx36.png) - it needs some work, but I believe this should get you headed in the right direction.

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks for the help

Comment: Excellent.  Glad I could help.